# Make user required to complete profile info first before checking out

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django and trying to create my first e-commerce website.

I have a "User" app which the user could go there and enter their name, and address.
The problem i'm facing is that I want the user to complete the profile first before they could checkout from the shopping cart. If the user didn't create the profile yet, i want to redirect them to that url.

I have a very little knowledge on authentication, so please someone help giving me some clue

Comment: post what you have tried,like your views and models

Answer (score 0):

Add something to the User Model:

```
 class User(models.Model):
    ...
    profileComplete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And after completing the form, set `profileComplete` to `True`

Then create some `middleware` that checks if the profile is completed, and redirect the user if prfile is not complete.

Another way would be to create a `decorator` that checks the value of `User.profileComplete`

Answer (score -2):

if you need to check does user authenticated you can use folowing code

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    #some code here
else:
    return redirect('url to fill profile')
```

if you need to check does address exist in user profile you can use

```
if request.user.address:
    #some code here
else:
    return redirect('url to fill profile')
```